# How to make my custom type to appear in Visual Studio Settings Editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, application-settings

Suppose I have a custom type I want to use to allow users to configure details for a `Person` in `app.config`:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make sure "`Person`" appears in the list of types when I click on "`Browse...`" in the *Visual Studio Settings Editor* for the project (after dropping down the combo box for "`Type`")?

Comment: It should be automatically visible

Comment: Unfortunately it is not automatically visible for me (using either VS2012 or VS2013).

Answer (score 1):

[**1:**  ]
At [MSDN article about **`Select a Type Dialog Box`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/776fzdxt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I found this:

> The **available referenced assemblies** display in a tree control. Open a referenced assembly to display namespaces for the assembly.

So, One of your solution is to make your own assembly, referencing it to your solution and you can find it in your `Type Dialog Box`.

---

As my searches I found that the `System.Drawing.Point` is available ([With this structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?query=ComVisibleAttribute)) and the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` is not available ([With this structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) in `Type Dialog Box` that both are `struct` with same `attributes` so I found showing a `Type` in that `Dialog Box` is not depended on making a `struct` and using some `attributes`.

---

[**2:**  ]
In another way you can have a `string` type setting with a value like `fName; lName` and add a constructor or a method to your class that sets your class properties to that you want like below:

```
public Person(string fullName, char seperator = ';')
{
    if (fullName.IndexOf(seperator) > 0)
    {
        firstname = fullName.Substring(0, fullName.IndexOf(seperator) - 1);
        lastname = fullName.Substring(fullName.IndexOf(seperator) + 1);
    }
}
```

---

[**3:**  ]
This is not a good way but can be noticed, You can edit the type of your setting manually by editing it in `Settings.Designer.cs` like below:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("fName; lName")]
public Person Test
{
    get {
        return ((Person)(this["Test"]));
    }
    set {
        this["Test"] = value;
    }
}
```

But this will force you to make some changes on your class, and whenever you save then `Settings` you should do that changes again and again.